# autocompletetextview long text

Tags: java, android

i have an autocomplete textfield in android. if the text i select is longer than the width of the field the cursor moves to the end of the selection upon selection.

here is the drop down

```
|sample text 1           |
|sample text 2           |
|sample selection 3      |
|more sample selection 4 |
|sample text 5           |
```

and if i choose the long selection, it displays like this:

```
|ample selection 4|
```

i would prefer the selection was displayed from the left like this:

```
|more sample selec|
```

ive tried gravity but that doesnt work.
it may be to do with moving the cursor back to the beginning of the selection perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right: setting the cursor position will achieve the result you're looking for. Here's how you can do it.

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        autoCompleteTextView.setSelection(0); // move cursor to position 0
    }
});
```